# Hide row in Gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to hide a row when its button clicked in my gridview. Does anyone have a solution for this, I am all yours,

Code behind:

```
    protected void gvShow_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "removethis")
        {
            Guid id = Guid.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            UsersBL.DeleteUserByUserId(id);

        }
        else
        {
            //hide the row
        }
    }
```

Comment: try this  `e.Row.Visible = false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this - Add RowDataBound event and do like this:

`e.Row.Visible = false;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the row-object and then you can hide it, it's a little tricky:

```
protected void gvShow_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.CommandName == "removethis")
        {
           GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
           row.Visible = false;
        }
}
```